# PIXI.js ColorMatrixFilter Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[number, ...number[]]'?

Tags: javascript, typescript, pixi.js, colormatrixfilter

I wrote a function, it was always works fine

```
getLightMatrix(value: number): number[] {
    let m = [
        1,0,0,0,value,
        0,1,0,0,value,
        0,0,1,0,value,
        0,0,0,1,0,
    ];
    return m;
}
let m = new PIXI.filters.ColorMatrixFilter();
m.matrix = getLightMatrix(1);
```

Recently, when I used Pixi 6.2.0, will display
error TS2322: Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'ColorMatrix'.
Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[number, ...number[]]'.
Source provides no match for required element at position 0 in target.

If I assign a number[] directly to it

```
let m = new PIXI.filters.ColorMatrixFilter();
m.matrix = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0];
```

Pass verification, How do I modify it?

Comment: Change the return type of the function to `[number, ...number[]]`. Seems like a "smart way" to type check that the array is non empty, but risking a breaking change for that sounds not so smart ...

Comment: I tried to change the return type of the function, but it was same error